# Can 行くな change to 行くぬ?

Tags: meaning

Can 行くな change to 行くぬ with the same meaning "Don't go"?

Comment: I assume this is based on the 行かない～行かぬ pair, but the negative imperative な is a very old particle, attested even in the Kojiki I believe. What prompted this question?

Comment: I just curious. I see that な when combine with a dictionary form of a verb produces the negative imperative. And ぬ can be replaced with ない .So can な replaced with ぬ with the same meaning?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From your comment:

> I see that な when combined with a dictionary form of a verb produces the negative imperative. And ぬ can be replaced with ない. So can な replaced with ぬ with the same meaning?

First of all, no. The な is a particle (助詞). ぬ and ない are auxiliaries (助動詞).

The negative imperative な is attached to the attributive form (連体形) of a verb:

> 行く+な → 行くな "Don't go!"

The negative auxiliaries ぬ and ない are attached to the imperfective form (未然形) of a verb. The 未然形 of 行く is 行か, so:

> 行く+ない → 行**か**ない / 行く+ぬ → 行**か**ぬ "don't go"

In modern Japanese, the auxiliaries ない and ぬ don't have the imperative form (命令形).

<sub>(In classical Japanese, the terminal form of ぬ is ず, and its imperative form is ざれ.)</sub>

Comment: This is a very good description. I wouldn't even begin to know how to translate, so this is very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

そんな言葉は聞いたことない、ね。
I have never heard that, and my first thought would be it's a misprint or someone misheard. (apparently not a classical usage, so edited)

Comment: Any suggestion on what is not helpful about my answer? It's very frustrating, so I appreciate some edit/comment if you are voting down.